# Setting a border around an Expander button resizes it slightly

Tags: c#, wpf, border, expander

I am making an `Expander` style, and I noticed that when the border around the `Expander`'s `ToggleButton` goes from 0 to a non-zero value - "0,0,1,1", in this case - it is resized slightly, to shrink inside the border:

[image: Expander]

Not exactly app-breaking... But annoying that I can't fix it. How can I circumvent this? I need the `Border` in the `ToggleButton`'s style to be 0 when the `Expander` is collapsed (since `Expander` has its own border that would make it look like a doubly-thick border) and non-zero when expanded (since I want the button to be separated by a border from the rest of the content).

`ToggleButton` style:

```
<Style x:Key="ExpanderRightHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{StaticResource MutedColorBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Expander.Border}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" CornerRadius="0" Height="22" Width="22">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Margin="0">
                        <ui:ColorableImage x:Name="img" Margin="0" Padding="2" Background="{StaticResource MutedColorBrush}" Color="Black"  Height="{Binding Path=Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}" Width="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}" Source="Assets/Images/filter.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,12,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="0,0,1,1" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource MainColorBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="img" Value="{StaticResource MainColorBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="img" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

`Expander` style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F0F0F0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="0" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="0" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="5,0,5,10" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Auto"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Possibly related - the `ColorableImage` control:

ColorableImage.xaml (x:Name="This"):

```
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="originalImage"  Visibility="Hidden"  Stretch="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=Stretch}" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
    <Image x:Name="displayedImage" Visibility="Visible" Stretch="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=Stretch}" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
</Grid>
```

ColorableImage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class ColorableImage : UserControl
{
    // This is so that SourcePropertyChanged will not execute when ColorPropertyChanged does. ColorPropertyChanged changes Source,
    // so SourcePropertyChanged is called in turn. This will change originalImage to the newly colored Source, which is incorrect.
    // "Wrapping" the statement that changes the binding in ColorPropertyChanged with this boolean and making it a condition in 
    // SourcePropertyChanged makes SourcePropertyChanged executre only when Source is directly changed, whether through C# or XAML.
    private static bool changedByColor = false;

    public ColorableImage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(Color), typeof(ColorableImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ColorPropertyChanged));
    public Color Color
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ColorableImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(SourcePropertyChanged));
    public ImageSource Source
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StretchProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Stretch", typeof(Stretch), typeof(ColorableImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Stretch.Uniform));
    public Stretch Stretch
    {
        get { return (Stretch)GetValue(StretchProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(StretchProperty, value);
            this.originalImage.Stretch = value;
            this.displayedImage.Stretch = value;
        }
    }

    private static void ColorPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ColorableImage cimg = (ColorableImage)sender;

        Binding binding = new Binding("Source")
        {
            ElementName = "originalImage",
            Converter = new HighlightImageConverter(),
            ConverterParameter = cimg.Color,
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
        };

        changedByColor = true;
        cimg.displayedImage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, binding);
        changedByColor = false;
    }

    private static void SourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!changedByColor)
        {
            ColorableImage cimg = (ColorableImage)sender;

            cimg.originalImage.Source = cimg.Source;
            cimg.displayedImage.Source = cimg.Source;
            // Note: #00000000 is the value for the "null color"
            if (cimg.Color != null && !cimg.Color.ToString().Equals("#00000000"))
            {
                // Color the new image (this is necessary if the user sets the source after the color; the color would be lost, otherwise)
                ColorPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just spent ages setting all of your code up in a new project and trying to fix all of the broken references that you left in there but there's so much missing that it could not reproduce your problem. -1 for wasting my time.

Comment: I believe the only broken references of mine in there are colors. Everything else is a resource that comes with Expander if you copy the default template

Comment: Paste it into a new project and you'll see what else is missing. Either way, it was just too much work and very disappointing that it didn't even work at the end of it.

Comment: Hm... Only thing I got besides the colors was `ColorableImage`, which is with the post... It works for me after I change the colors. Did you get everything from the default `Expander` stylings?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably avoid that problem by setting the `BorderBrush` to transparent, instead of setting the `BorderThickness` to 0.

You might possibly have to add an extra container...
I don't feel like testing this, since the question is old and [@Sheridan wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435119/setting-a-border-around-an-expander-button-resizes-it-slightly/25692423#comment37816742_24435119) that he had trouble making it work.